# How do you hide/disable the active tab's border color?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do you hide/disable the active tab's border color?  In the screenshot below, it is the orange line at the top of the tab:

[image: tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, there is no color option specified for that (are you sharing a settings.json file?)

To remove the color of the top border, look at your setting.json and find `workbench.colorCustomizations` and within it, find `tab.activeBorderTop` and delete it:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeBorderTop": "#ff0000"  //delete this line
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Clarification*: This answer is different from the currently accepted one which suggests **deleting** a setting, which may not exist as in my situation (fresh install). This answer **adds** a setting.

---

In VSCode 1.83.1 I "hid" the top borders by setting a transparent color

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "tab.activeBorderTop": "#0000"
}
```

The hex code is of format `#RGBA`. `A` (Alpha) is the important part; setting it to `0` makes the color invisible. Setting the `R`, `G`, and `B` parts shouldn't matter as they'll be fully transparent anyway.

The old default themes didn't seem to have a top border for active tabs, but the new ones do (e.g. Modern Dark), so alternatively using the old themes would also remove the top borders.